# Creating a column of hyperlinks in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a column of products that I need to convert to hyperlinks. Can this be done in one shot or do they have to be done individually?

Comment: So you have a list of like `1`,`1293`,`19328`? And you want to add them to a link, say `http://www.example.com/product/1` or `http://www.example.com/product/19328`? You can use this `=Hyperlink("http://www.example.com/product/"&A1,"Link")`.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow following steps:

- Select the complete column OR all values in column.
- Pres CTRL+K
- This will pop-up a small window, which will ask the hyperlink URL.
- Type the URL there or use the Browsed Pages/Current Folder/Recent Files for hyperlink.

Below image shows the way to do it:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Say we have a list of IDs in column **A** and an equivalent list of IDs elsewhere on the same worksheet:

[image]

Select the cells in column **A** and run this short macro:

```
Sub HyperMaker()
    Dim r As Range, v As String, j As Range, subad As String
    With ActiveSheet
        For Each r In Selection
            v = r.Text
            Set f = Cells.Find(What:=v, After:=r)
            subad = .Name & "!" & f.Address(0, 0)
            .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=r, Address:="", SubAddress:=subad, TextToDisplay:=v
        Next r
    End With
End Sub
```

and they will be converted into hyperlinks.